# how can I display an image in html, if I am having a localhost object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

the file is saved at localhost , I tried to download it on my client site directory but I did not get any solution for that also.
Here is my object

```
{link: "/home/company/S…1-eKdj#S0mkzO!3J__google-200x200.7714256da16f.png", name: "Courier", time: "2017-06-20 04:50:50.824948", $$hashKey: "object:3479"}
```

I tried to append the link after my localhost URL

here is my html img tag's src link:

http://172.16.0.72:8134/pm/home/company/S%E2%80%A61-eKdj#S0mkzO!3J__google-200x200.7714256da16f.png

but still it is not displaying the required image..

Answer (score 0):

If the object is on the scope, then you can do this:

HTML

```
<img ng-src="{{image.link}}">
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.image = {link: "/home/company/S…1-eKdj#S0mkzO!3J__google-200x200.7714256da16f.png", name: "Courier", time: "2017-06-20 04:50:50.824948", $$hashKey: "object:3479"};
```

Working code: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PUnYOiJdUYW90cdRV9Ld?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this following solutions

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
      link: "https://www.w3schools.com/angular/pic_angular.jpg",
      name: "Courier",
      time: "2017-06-20 04:50:50.824948",
      $$hashKey: "object:3479"
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img ng-src="{{obj.link}}" alt="test">
</div>
```

Hope this is help you

Comment: the link does not starts from "https:/" or "http:/", it starts from '/home/' and file is saved at localhost folder on back-end server .. due to which link is /home/company/S…1-eKdj#S0mkzO!3J__google-200x200.7714256da16f.png